# Java 8 Stream Collect Sets

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have two maps, namely

```
Map<String, Set<String>> courseTeacherMap = {course1: [teacher1, teacher2], ...}
Map<String, Set<String>> teacherStudentMap = {teacher1: [student1, student2], ...}
```

And I defined a class `courseStudentPair` that has a very simple structure

```
public class courseStudentPair{
    String studentName; // Taken from teacherStudentMap
    String courseName; // Taken from courseTeacherMap
}
```

And my goal is to get a `Set<courseStudentPair>` out of the two maps. As long as a teacher A is teaching a course C, every student that is in the value set of key A in `teacherStudentMap` is considered to be a student taking C.

For example, given

```
Map<String, Set<String>> courseTeacherMap = {c1: [t1], c2:[t2], c3:[t1, t2]}
Map<String, Set<String>> teacherStudentMap = {t1: [s1], t2:[s1, s2]}
```

The result should be *(student, course) denotes a courseStudentPair object in the example below*

```
Set<courseStudentPair> result = [(c1, s1), (c2, s1), (c2, s2), (c3, s1), (c3, s2)]
```

It's quite straightforward to do it with for loops, but I am learning the stream function in Java 8 and this seems quite complicated to me. You can assume the `courseStudentPair` class has constructor or builder defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same spirit, you can generate each combination of (course, teacher) and then lookup for the students associated with this teacher. This may generate duplicates (for instance (c3, s1)), so be sure your `CourseStudentPair` class implements `equals()` and `hashCode()` based on those two fields.

```
import static java.util.Collections.emptySet;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

...

Set<CourseStudentPair> result =
    courseTeacherMap.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue()
                                   .stream()
                                   .flatMap(t -> teacherStudentMap.getOrDefault(t, emptySet()).stream().map(s -> new CourseStudentPair(e.getKey(), s))))
                    .collect(toSet());
/*
 Output:

 CourseStudentPair{studentName='c1', courseName='s1'}
 CourseStudentPair{studentName='c2', courseName='s2'}
 CourseStudentPair{studentName='c2', courseName='s1'}
 CourseStudentPair{studentName='c3', courseName='s2'}
 CourseStudentPair{studentName='c3', courseName='s1'}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Pair<String, String>> result = courseTeacherMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(entry -> Optional.ofNullable(entry.getValue())
                    .orElse(new HashSet<>())
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(teacher -> Optional.ofNullable(teacherStudentMap.get(teacher))
                            .orElse(new HashSet<>())
                            .stream()
                            .map(student -> Pair.of(entry.getKey(), student))))
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I edited to make it null-safe, in case a teacher has no students for example or your `Map` might have a key mapped to null for example.

Comment: I’d use `Collections.emptySet()` instead of `new HashSet<>()`. And the much simpler `map.getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptySet())` instead of `Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key)) .orElse(new HashSet<>())`…